# date time value minus numeric doesnt work

Tags: apex, trigger, datetime

i have a trigger that will update a custom date field in my case but it seems like my calculation is wrong.

This is my trigger:

```
c.SLA_Cont_Time__c = System.now() - c.SLA_Days_mins__c;
```

c.SLA_Cont_Time__c is my custom date/time field and c.SLA_Days_mins__c is a numeric field that i need to minus it to get latest value. but my c.SLA_Cont_Time__c keep getting the System.now() value. why it will not take the after subtraction value?

Comment: Please try to find specific tags and avoid using very general tags such as 'salesforce-crm'. This helps you attract the right people to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking a look at the [`date` instance methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Date_instance_methods.htm).

You'll find a method called `addDays` that'll do the trick.  Also, `System.now()` returns a `datetime` rather than a `date`, so if you want today's date, use `date.today()`.

```
c.SLA_Cont_Time__c = date.today().addDays(-1*c.SLA_Days_mins__c);

// I multiplied c.SLA_Days_mins__c by -1 before so we subtract days
```

---

For reference:

- [date static methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Date_static_methods.htm)
- [datetime methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Comment: Actually i need this field for my entitlement. so i need it as a date time value as my entitlement count against my business hour.

c.SLA_Days_mins__c actually is a minute that i calculate from 2 date field. I wanted to know how many mins used for my entitlement milestone then continue from there. That's why i need to minus c.SLA_Days_mins__c

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
c.SLA_Cont_Time__c = (System.now().getTime() - c.SLA_Days_mins__c.getTime())/1000;
```

Because  getTime() :

```
Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this DateTime object.
```

but why do you need Data/Time field?
Did you considered use formula?